# log4net Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform. with WSL2

Tags: log4net, asp.net-core-3.1, wsl-2

I am using log4net latest version and getting error log4net
**Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.** when trying to debug application in WSL2

```
Mymethod(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{

var properties = loggingEvent.GetProperties()

...
}
```

Any idea what wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A follow up on @Alex answer.

Until the *WindowsPrincipal* dependency is fixed on *nix platforms, downgrade log4net nuget to 2.0.9.

FOLLOW UP: It is fixed from log4net v2.0.12 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-652

Comment: Yes that is what i am doing since a month

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in log4Net when it attempts to retrieve the UserName; it's using a `WindowsPrincipal`. This isn't supported on Linux.

There's an unreleased fix to set the user to `SystemInfo.NotAvailableText` if the platform doesn't support `WindowsPrincipal`.

I will update this answer if I come up with a workaround